# Simple delegate method is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I have searched for similar question, but I just cannot understand why this does not work. I did everything following a tutorial and tutorial project works right now, but I do everything fairly the same and no result.

I have my InboxViewController with table view with list of articles. I have another view (AccordionViewController.h) where I can chose to sort by date or rating.

This is the second controller: AccordionViewController.h

```
@protocol OptionSelectionDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)selectedFilter:(NSMutableArray *)articles;

@end

@interface AccordionTableViewController  : UITableViewController  {

    NSArray *topItems;
    NSMutableArray *subItems; // array of arrays
    NSInteger currentExpandedIndex;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* articles;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<OptionSelectionDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

in InboxViewController.m I did:

```
@interface InboxViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, OptionSelectionDelegate>

. . .

#pragma mark - State Selection Delegate
-(void)selectedFilter:(NSMutableArray *)articles1
{
    self.articles = articles1;
    for (int i=0; i<self.articles.count; i++) {
        Article* a = [self.articles objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Inbox Sorted Array 1: %d -  %@",i, a.date);
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

I call this method in AccordionVC in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like this:

```
. . .
self.articles = [sortedArticles mutableCopy];
                [self.delegate  selectedFilter:self.articles];
. . .
```

Thank you. Will add anything needed.

Comment: Where did you set the delegate?

Comment: Where do you set self.delegate? //Edit: what Cutetare said 9sec before me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AccordionVC, you are missing a line:

```
  self.delegate = .. //some reference to a InboxViewController
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I set it in prepareForSegue of InboxViewController and it instantly worked.